# What scope does unit testing cover in a weakly typed language?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing

The best way I can express my question is with an example.

```js
class foo{
  constructor(size) {
    this.bar = new Array(size);
  }
  baz(index) {
    this.body[index] = true;
  }
}
```

Ignoring the constructor, assume we're unit testing `baz()`. baz is **logically** expected to take an input `index` that's between `0` and `bar.length - 1`, but the following can also compile:

1. `baz(['hey'])`
2. `baz(5) // with an array size of 2`
3. `baz(true)`
4. `baz('0')`

Now, I've been doing a lot of research on **what** we're actually testing with unit tests, and the best answer I can gather from what I read all around, is that, we're testing the function's behavior within the bounds of its logical contract with what/who's calling it. AKA, test implementation while implicitly assuming that **it' called correctly**.

I'm fully satisfied with this, but what I want to know is, where do we draw that line? None of the examples above will cause a typeerror, but I can disregard 1,3 and probably 4 if I'm to follow what I learned above.

But should I care about 2? Or do I also assume that the function's 'contract' will be upheld not only in terms of the inputs' implicit typing, but also their logical bounds.

Should I test and account for example 2 in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether the contract says "*…and for all other inputs, the function throws an exception*" - in which case you should test that it is thrown as expected - or whether the contract simply says (or implies) "*…and don't call it with anything else, it may not work or do unpredictable things*" (i.e. [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) - in which case you don't need to test it.

A number outside of the expected range (your example case 2), and a value of an unexpected type (cases 1, 3, 4) may independently fall on either side of that distinction. You can draw the line wherever you want. Just make sure to gain bonus points by documenting where you drew it.

Comment: This is great, so in essence, as long as I properly document and implicitly 'show' what the input should be, then I've defined the function's contract sufficiently enough to not have to test the inputs, (all of the cases in this example). So while JS is weakly typed, we leave the understanding of what the types and their ranges **should be** to the person reading the code as long as we give them the right hints. Or, in other words define the contract in the function without checks, and without tests.

Comment: No, you don't define the contract inside the function, and require someone to read the code, or do it implicitly with example inputs or hints. You write the contract down as prose, in the documentation or doc-comments above the function. Be explicit about what types of values you expect and which in which ranges they are valid. JS might not have type annotations in the code, or a compiler typechecking them, but it still has types.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much! Now I'm more confident about knowing what to test & check (nothing in the case of the example in the question) and what not to.

Comment: Can you please take a look at [this class](https://jsbin.com/laziqoreze/edit?js) and let me know if it's documented well enough to forgo any checks like `if (shipLength < 1) throw new Error()`, if you were to code this, what would you do differently?

Comment: @Brother58697 Yes, that seems reasonable - much better than many I've seen. If I were to pick some nits, I'd ask where the method to "*check if all parts of the ship have been hit*" went, I'd put some of the documentation (especially what the array represents) on the `class` itself not on the constructor, and I'd say "integer larger than 0" instead of "number that should not be 0" :-)

Comment: You're awesome Bergi. I hadn't written the method yet hahahah :P Thank you so much! And I'm all for your tips and will apply them.